# Sumar ramas en prolog

Tags: prolog

Hola soy principiante en prolog y estoy estudiante sobre arboles ternarios llevo tiempo tratando de resolver el siguiente ejercicio
Recorrer a profundidad un árbol ternario y que calcule la suma de cada rama desde la raíz hasta una hoja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El árbol ternario se representa como una estructura `arbol(Raiz, Hijo1, Hijo2, Hijo3)`, donde `Raiz` es un número, `Hijo1`, `Hijo2` e `Hijo3` son árboles ternarios, y `vacio` representa un árbol vacío:

- El sumatorio de un árbol vacío (`vacio`) es 0.
- El sumatorio de un árbol no vacío (`arbol(R,X,Y,Z)`) es la suma de la raíz (`R`) más el sumatorio de cada uno de los hijos (`X`, `Y` y `Z`).

Representado en prolog:

```
suma(vacio, 0).
suma(arbol(R,X,Y,Z), N) :-
    suma(X, A),
    suma(Y, B),
    suma(Z, C),
    N is R+A+B+C.
```

Comment: Ayudanos a conservar la caidad del sitio respondiendo únicamente pregubtas que cumplan con lo definido en el [help].  Este tipo de preguntas que son tareas deben al menos tener un [mcve].